# The roots of the derivative $P'(z)$ of the polynomial $P(z)\in\mathbb C[x]$ lie in the convex hull of the set of roots of $P(z)$.

Tags: complex-numbers, contest-math

Assume $S=\{z_1,z_2,...,z_k\}, z_i\in \mathbb C$$, C(S)$  and define $$C(S):=\{z=a_1z_1+a_2z_2+...+a_kz_k | a_i\ge0 ,a_1+a_2+...+a_k=1\}$$ where  $$A:=\{z\in \mathbb C:f(z)=0 \},~~~\text{and}~~~A':=\{z\in \mathbb C:f'(z)=0\}$$ such that    $f$  is polynomial ($f\in P[\mathbb C]$) and $\deg(f)\ge2$.

How to prove that $$ C(A')\subset C(A)$$ 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the Gauss–Lucas theorem and you can find a proof [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Lucas_theorem#Proof). It says that the roots 
of the derivative $P'(z)$ of the polynomial $P(z)\in\mathbb C[x]$ lie in the convex hull of the set of roots of $P(z)$.

In case $\deg P=3$ there is a stronger result ( someone might say [the most marvelous](http://mathtourist.blogspot.com/2008/05/most-marvelous-theorem.html) [theorem](http://www1.american.edu/cas/mathstat/People/kalman/pdffiles/mardenMH.pdf)) called [Marden](http://www4.uwm.edu/letsci/math/alumni/history/marden.cfm)'s theorem but actually is Jörg Siebeck's( see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_misnamed_theorems)). The theorem is the following:

> Let $z_1,z_2,z_3$ be the roots of the polynomial $P(z)$ (assume that are nonlinear) and $T$ the triangle with vertices $z_1,z_2,z_3$. The Gauss–Lucas theorem says that the roots of $P'(z)$, say $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$, lie in $T$. Let $E$ be the [ellipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Elements_of_an_ellipse) inscribed in $T$ and tangent to the sides of $T$ at their midpoints. Marden's theorem says that $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ are the foci of $E$.

It was named Marden's theorem by [Dan Kalman](http://www1.american.edu/cas/mathstat/People/kalman/) because he first read the theorem at Marden's wonderful book [Geometry of Polynomials](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821815032).  For more on the history and a proof of this theorem see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marden%27s_theorem#CITEREFLinfield1920) and [this](http://mathdl.maa.org/images/upload_library/22/Ford/Kalman.pdf).

Answer (score 5):

Edit: following Arkamis comment, I will stress out that $C(S)$ is a very natural object called the convex hull of $S$. In the real case, this yields segments and the result follows therefore from Rolle's theorem.

You just have to show that the roots of $f'$ are in the convex hull of the roots of $f$. Then $C(f')$ will automatically be contained in $C(f)$.

Let $f(z)$ be a degree $n$ polynomial with possibly repeated roots $(z_1,\ldots,z_n)$. We have the partial fraction decomposition:
$$
\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}=\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{1}{z-z_j}.
$$
Pick any root $z$ of $f'$. If $z$ is a root of $f$, there is nothing to prove. If not, the lhs above is $0$ and the rhs is well-defined.

Now manipulate this equation to prove the claim, using 
$$
\frac{1}{z-z_j}=\frac{\bar{z}-\bar{z_j}}{|z-z_j|^2}.
$$

Comment: Just to add some commentary for the OP, the set $C$ is a *convex combination* of $\{ z_k\}$, so the roots being in convex hull isn't something that comes out of nowhere, but is a result of the definition of convexity and the definition of the set $C$ in this problem.